# Monitor Linux process with STAT status

Tags: linux, awk, zombie-process

Don't know if anyone has idea on how I can monitor Zombie processes using Zabbix. Zabbix agent currently has a predefined template "proc.num[,,,]" which I can use to monitor 'zombie' processes but this only shows STAT with 'Z'.

I have a script that can check for STAT with either 'X' or 'Z' i.e X = Dead & Z = Zombie

```
ps aux | awk '$8=="X" || $8=="Y"' | wc -l
```

How can this script be used in Zabbix

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured this out. Using Zabbix Agent template called 'system.run':

```
system.run[ps aux | awk '$8=="X" || $8=="Y"'|wc -l,]
```